# Imported model has weird, unusuable UV Layout

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

When I import a model I got using Ninja Ripper and export it to Blender using Noesis to convert it to other file types (including FBX and OBJ), the UV Map Layout is a long straight vertical line going up and down the right hand side of the UV Editor window. The guide for Ninja Ripper suggests using "forced" to get more duplicates of the model and hope that one of them has a better UV Layout, but none of them do. Obviously I can just unwrap the mesh myself, but then it won’t fit the diffuse or normal texture maps that came with the model. Does anybody know what could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: I exported from Ninja Ripper RIP files to a wide variety of file types including FBX, OBJ, and others using Noesis to Blender. There are many duplicate meshes from Ninja Ripper, but they all look exactly the same, and I'm not sure how "multiple UV maps" work. The guide on Ninja Ripper suggested that I simply use "forced" mode to get more rips and find one with a good UV Map layout, but so far that hasn't helped, because all the ones I've tried had the exact same UV layout.

Comment: Hey :). I don't have experience with N-Ripper, but perhaps others do. You can edit your comment into the question, to make it more specific. (About [multiple UV maps](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/uv_image/uv/layout_management.html))

Comment: OK, I updated it. I don't think multiple UV maps is the issue... all the ones Ninja Ripper gives me are exact duplicates of each other.